# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' - ios google sign in

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm implementing the google sign in process taken from this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?configured=true&ver=swift

as I can see there the author wrote:

> In these examples, the view controller is a subclass of
>   UIViewController. If, in your project, the class that implements
>   GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of UIViewController, implement
>   the signInWillDispatch:error:, signIn:presentViewController:, and
>   signIn:dismissViewController: methods of the GIDSignInUIDelegate
>   protocol.

so following his advices I wrote as follows:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {



func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
}

// [START openurl]
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
// [END openurl]

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}

// [START signin_handler]
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            print("Signed in!")
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
// [END signin_handler]

// [START disconnect_handler]
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "ToggleAuthUINotification",
            object: nil,
            userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnected."])
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

I also have a class called `LoginScreen.swift` that contains:

```
import UIKit

class LoginScreen: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

     GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
    print("Nothing!")
}

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


}
```

and when I run the app I see the button `sign in with google`. But when I click it, I see the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'When |allowsSignInWithWebView| is enabled, uiDelegate must
either be a |UIViewController| or implement the
|signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| 
methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'
```

What is the problem here? I thought I included the necessary methods...

============ EDIT - as a follow up to @emrys57 questions:

I have the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file attached in my project:

[image]

When I comment out the 3 methods (`presentViewController`, `dismissViewController` and `signInWillDispatch`) nothing changes - I'm still getting the same error..

About the screens - this is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

and I want to display the google log in button on the 3rd screen.

The second screen here contains a `Tutorial` and its code is so far as follows:

```
import UIKit

class Tutorial: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let background = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()
        background.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

And one more thing - when I turn on the app I see now the google login button:

[image]

And when I click it - I'm getting the mentioned error:

```
2016-02-13 09:47:49.578 myapp[20870:800499] *** Terminating app due
to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'When
|allowsSignInWithWebView| is enabled, uiDelegate must either be a
|UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and
|signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'

*** First throw call stack:
(...)
```

so I guess the LoginScreen is running when I hit the button...

=========== another EDIT:

When I copied the code from my `LoginScreen` to the class `ViewController` and added button there - everything worked fine, I see a google sign in button and I can log in! BUT - the button appears on the first screen of the app and that's not what I want. I want it to appear on the 3rd screen (after the tutorial). Does anybody know what is going on here and why I can't put the login button on the 3rd screen?

Comment: It's not clear quite where LoginScreen is instantiated. When this message appears, is LoginScreen Running, so the uiDelegate has been set up? And did you add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file? And apparently you only need the 3 UIDelegate methods if your Class is not a UIViewcontroller. But yours is. So what happens if you comment out the 3 delegate methods?

Comment: @emrys57 I added answers to your questions, please see my edit above, thanks!

Comment: That's getting harder. I'll try and run your code if this is still a problem later today, but I must go and pay attention to my wife now.

Comment: @emrys57 I found a solution... of course the error was caused by my oversight, but it's a great lesson for the future. Thanks for your involvement though, it was nice to have a feeling that I'm not the only one person out there looking for a solution :)

Comment: @randomuser1 i'm having the same issue as i came across your problem. What was the solution if u dont mind me asking?

Comment: @user3497437 so yeah, it was really my fault back then... when I added a new screen to the story board I forgot to fill the form `Custom class`. When I realized about that and filled the field `Class` and `Module` - it started working fine... I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 13):

**Updated for Swift 5/ google sign-in for ios sdk 5:**

used below lines of code in **signIn Button Action Method**:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

> Note: Comments above lines of code if you are using it anywhere in
>   your ViewController...! otherwise it will be fine.

Enjoy Learning....!

Answer (score 10):

I know it's too late but will help for others if you put the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self` into viewDidAppear instead viewDidLoad, that's worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

`func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!)` is a method from the `GIDSignInUIDelegate` protocol but the code above states that `AppDelegate` adopts the `GIDSignInDelegate` (not "UI") protocol, and your `GIDSignInUIDelegate` does not provide the methods. Either the classes are adopting the wrong protocols or the methods are in the wrong classes.

Comment: Ok so I moved the two methods `presentViewController` and `dismissViewController` to my `LoginScreen` class, but it didn't do the trick, unfortunately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with new code, or ask a new question. Hard to see from here. Plus, sorry, I'm off to bed. Good Luck!

Comment: I edited the code in my question after your suggestions, the problem still appears though

Answer (score 0):

Not the problem for this question, but this may also happen due to a automatic Obj-C to Swift 3 naming generation, causing method signatures of GIDSignInUIProtocol to be different than what's expected by Google's SDK.

**Adding these forward methods to the `GIDSignInUIProtocol` implementation will solve the issue for this case -**

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.sign(signIn, present: viewController)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.sign(signIn, dismiss: viewController)
}
```

Comment: but this is also not working for me! Is this a sdk fault

Answer (score 0):

In case its helpful I posted the root cause of this error in my case [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888816/swift-uidelegate-must-either-be-a-uiviewcontroller-or-implement-the-signinpre/52286433#52286433) in this other post.

Answer (score 0):

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = self