# Swift - uiDelegate must either be a UIViewController or implement the signIn:presentViewController: & signIn:dismissViewController: methods

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

From the `Crashlytics`, we are receiving a large amount of crash reports in the Google Login process. The crash report is as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1837f2db0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182e57f80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1837f2cf8 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Hello English                  0x100583d18 -[GIDSignIn assertValidUIDelegate] (GIDSignIn.m:512)
4  Hello English                  0x1005861dc -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] (GIDSignIn.m:961)
5  Hello English                  0x10058a0e4 -[GIDSignInButton pressed] (GIDSignInButton.m:385)
6  UIKit                          0x188988be8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
7  UIKit                          0x188988b64 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
8  UIKit                          0x188970870 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
9  UIKit                          0x188988454 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
10 UIKit                          0x188988084 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
11 UIKit                          0x188980c20 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
12 UIKit                          0x18895104c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
13 UIKit                          0x18894f628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1837a909c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1837a8b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1837a6830 __CFRunLoopRun
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1836d0c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
18 GraphicsServices               0x184fb8088 GSEventRunModal
19 UIKit                          0x1889ba088 UIApplicationMain
20 Hello English                  0x10029b2cc main (AppDelegate.swift:26)
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x18326e8b8 (Missing)
```

We've tried so far:

1. Moved `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self` from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)`
2. We've also implemented all three methods of `GIDSignInUIDelegate` with no success.
3. Our view controller was not direct child of `UIViewController`, but now it is and the crashes are still counting.
4. We were using simple `UIButton`, so we thought that might be cause (though illogical, but we tried) of crash; we changed it to `GIDSignInButton`, but no reduction in crash-count.

For now we have removed the `Google Login` process, but it is not the solution. And strange thing is that we are unable to reproduce this crash at our end; we are only getting these crashes on `Crashlytics`.

So Anyone with any solution ?

Comment: Why don't you define the delegates?

Comment: See the edits, we have also tried it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371393/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinvalidargumentexception-ios-goo

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, The solutions we've tried are taken from the same link.

Comment: Hey @Ravi Sisodia, You able to find the solution for this. I am facing this issue.

Comment: @Satish, Unfortunately no. We have removed Google Sign in from our App.

Comment: this is sad, will update you if I find any solution

Comment: `signIn:presentViewController:` and  `signIn:dismissViewController:` methods are not relevant for iOS 11 and higher as they never get called anymore. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57112433/1433612

Answer (score 12):

Finally after putting much effort found a solution. 
My environment is

Swift 3,

iOS 10.3.x,

Xcode 8.3.2

Posting here a complete solution

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set delegates
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        let buttonFrame : CGRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
        let gdSignInButton = GIDSignInButton.init(frame:buttonFrame)
        gdSignInButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(gdSignInButton)

        //  gdSignInButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapSignOut(sender: self.gdSignInButton)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapSignOut(sender: GIDSignInButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    }

    func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {

        guard error == nil else {

            print("Error while trying to redirect : \(error)")
            return
        }

        print("Successful Redirection")
    }


    //MARK: GIDSignIn Delegate

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
    {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            print("User id is \(userId)")

            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            print("Authentication idToken is \(idToken)")
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            print("User full name is \(fullName)")
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            print("User given profile name is \(givenName)")
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            print("User family name is \(familyName)")
            let email = user.profile.email
            print("User email address is \(email)")
            // ...
        } else {
            print("ERROR ::\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    // Finished disconnecting |user| from the app successfully if |error| is |nil|.
    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
    {

    }



}
```

and my AppDelegate look like this.

```
import UIKit
import Google
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")



        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }


}
```

Comment: What is different in your solution? And, where did you called `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`

Answer (score 8):

you need to write these lines in `viewWillAppear` method of `UIViewController`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to implement Delegate of the Google and firebase properly
add like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate
```

in the ViewDidLoad add these lines

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply include the following

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    print("dismissing Google SignIn")
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    print("presenting Google SignIn")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **GoogleSignIn SDK 5.0** and above `GIDSignInUIDelegate` has been revoked

So Instead of

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

Add this below line, for conforming to presenting login view

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error and I observed it in two cases:

1. I created an @IBAction for the GoogleSignIn button and I included both of these lines in it:

   @IBAction func googleSignInButton(_ sender: Any) 
   {
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
   }

But the assignment of the uiDelegate needs to be in viewDidLoad and not in the @IBAction:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

2. In my other case the uiDelegate is a UIViewController so I didn't need to specify the additional methods. And like other posters here I was sure that I followed all of the directions yet was still seeing this error whenever I clicked on the Google SignIn button.

The root cause was that I created a new UIViewController class "DoLoginVC.swift" but I did not map this custom class to the UIViewController in the story board!  An oversight. Everything started working after I added the custom class mapping.

If you are seeing this error then go to your storyboard and go to the ViewController and verify that you have specified your custom class like in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me (iOS 10.0) was assigning my view controller as ui delegate in its viewDidAppear: method...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add this lines into viewDidAppear it works for me well

```
override    func    viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate    =    self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate    =    self
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that you have to implement following delegate methods:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

You can set this in `viewDidLoad()`.

---

#### Special Case

If you have Google Sign-In in multiple ViewControllers (e.g. in Register and Login screens), then you have to update delegates when screen is changed. To avoid conflicts, I would suggest to set it in `viewDidAppear()`. This will update delegate references with current ViewController, if you are switching screens back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

This error also be shown if you forgot to set your custom view Controller class to UIViewController Took on Storyboard.

To Do this -> goto your Storyboard -> select the View Controller -> goto Identity Explorer
and set your class if blank

See the image below for reference

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSf7l.png)